# (21) API called with NULL prepared statement

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, batch-processing

> I am currently working with sqlite database, android. I want to
>   import raw file which contains sql statements into my database. My
>   scenario as follows.

1. Read raw file as string
2. Split those sql statements by `;` symbol
3. Execute each statement inside a loop

But when I execute sql statements it throws errors such **`(21) API called with NULL prepared statement`** and **`(21) misuse at line 70084 of [b3bb660af9]`** after executing only one line of the file. I can't see any problem with my coding.

**Error Log**

```
03-08 14:56:41.652 15867-15867/com.sv.gauge D/EXECUTED SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF
03-08 14:56:41.662 15867-15867/com.sv.gauge E/SQLiteLog: (21) API called with NULL prepared statement
03-08 14:56:41.662 15867-15867/com.sv.gauge E/SQLiteLog: (21) misuse at line 70084 of [b3bb660af9]
03-08 14:56:41.672 15867-15867/com.sv.gauge D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-08 14:56:41.672 15867-15867/com.sv.gauge E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.sv.gauge, PID: 15867
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sv.gauge/com.sv.gauge.LoginActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
                                                          #################################################################
                                                          Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                          Caused By : not an error (code 0)
                                                          #################################################################
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2769)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1430)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
                                                           Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: not an error (code 0)
                                                          #################################################################
                                                          Error Code : 0 (SQLITE_OK)
                                                          Caused By : not an error (code 0)
                                                          #################################################################
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:904)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1814)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1743)
                                                              at com.sv.gauge.controller.GaugeDatabaseHelper.onCreate(GaugeDatabaseHelper.java:78)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                              at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
                                                              at com.sv.gauge.controller.GaugeDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase(GaugeDatabaseHelper.java:43)
                                                              at com.sv.gauge.controller.GaugeDatabaseHelper.<init>(GaugeDatabaseHelper.java:37)
                                                              at com.sv.gauge.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:39)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6178)
                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2648)
                                                                ... 10 more
```

**Code snippet to import raw sql file**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.database);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        String rawSql = builder.toString();

        String[] sqls = rawSql.split(";");
        for (String sql : sqls) {
            db.execSQL(sql);
            Log.d("EXECUTED SQL", sql);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Raw file which contain sql statements**

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE "domain" (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `description`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `first_step`    INTEGER NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO "domain" VALUES(1,'GENERATOR ROOM','take measurements of generator room',1);
CREATE TABLE "domain_step" (
    `id`    INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `domain_id` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `visual_type`   TEXT NOT NULL,
    `visual_link`   TEXT,
    `visual_description`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `next_step` INTEGER,
    `show_map`  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `last_step` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `map_from_previous_link`    TEXT,
    `enable_skip`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `skip_to_step`  INTEGER,
    `map_from_beginning_link`   TEXT,
    `value_type`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `value_hint`    TEXT,
    `default_value` TEXT,
    `default_from_value`    TEXT,
    `default_to_value`  TEXT,
    `report_description`    TEXT
);
INSERT INTO "domain_step" VALUES(1,1,'Safty Items','IMAGE',NULL,'Did you ware safety Items?

1) Ear protection

2) Helmet with light',2,0,0,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,'NONE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: it seems that you are appending another ; to the one already in the file

Comment: It's not a `;` . It's a line break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the sql file already has the ";" then

```
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
        builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
```

should be

```
try {
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        builder.append(line);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Jayvee. Actually It was worked. But sometimes in insert statements contains multi line texts to insert. So how can i handle it..?

Comment: you may need to add the line separator for each statement (sql) you call

Comment: actually line separators are belongs to insert statements, as follows.
`INSERT INTO "domain_step" VALUES(1,1,'Safty Items','IMAGE',NULL,'Did you ware safety Items?

1) Ear protection
2) Helmet with light',2,0,0,NULL,0,NULL,NULL,'NONE',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);`

Comment: Oops it's not showing line separators here. Let me update the question.

Comment: As the updated question some descriptions contains multi lines. So if I don't put ` builder.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` line, it will not update the database as required.

Comment: each sql line you submit for execution in db.execSQL(sql)  is delimited by ";" so the problem seems to be related to the linebreaks inside the insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

**Another option for other visitors**

I was getting this line because I had a comment in my SQL script that ended with a `;` character. Thus, it tried to execute just the comment by itself, thus producing the "NULL prepared statement" error.

```
-- version 1 of the database vocab table was
--
-- CREATE TABLE vocab
-- ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
--   date INTEGER,
--   list_id TEXT NOT NULL, -- this should have been INTEGER
--   mongol TEXT NOT NULL,
--   definition TEXT,
--   pronunciation TEXT,
--   audio TEXT,
--   FOREIGN KEY(list_id) REFERENCES lists(_id)
-- );

PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE vocab RENAME TO _vocab_old;

...
```

**Solutions**

You can solve this problem by doing any one of the following:

1. Remove the comment lines that end in a `;`
2. Add extra text after the `;`. I did this:

   ```
   -- version 1 of the database vocab table was
   --
   -- CREATE TABLE vocab
   -- ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
   --   date INTEGER,
   --   list_id TEXT NOT NULL, -- this should have been INTEGER
   --   mongol TEXT NOT NULL,
   --   definition TEXT,
   --   pronunciation TEXT,
   --   audio TEXT,
   --   FOREIGN KEY(list_id) REFERENCES lists(_id)
   -- ); -- end comment (comment lines cannot end with semicolon)
   ```
3. Alter the logic that runs the script so that it ignores any lines that begin with `--` and does not try to run them.

**Conclusion**

If you are getting this error, look for stray `;` characters that may be getting executed alone.